# Proof of an equivalent criterion for continuous functions in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, proof-explanation

From Munkres

> **Theorem 18.1.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces; let $f : X \to Y$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is continuous.
2. For every subset $A$ of $X$, one has $f ( \overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$.
3. For every closed set $B$ of $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$.
4. For each $x \in X$ and each neighborhood $V$ of $f (x)$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f (U) \subset V$.

For 4 $\Rightarrow$ 1 the proof given is

> (4) $\Rightarrow$ (1). Let $V$ be an open set of $Y$; let $x$ be a point of $f^{-1}(V)$. Then $f (x) \in V$, so that by hypothesis there is a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ such that $f (U_x ) \subset V$. Then $U_x \subset f^{-1}(V)$. It follows that $f^{-1}(V)$ can be written as the union of the open sets $U_x$, so that it is open.

I am not sure how the last statement follows. The mere fact that each $U_x \subset f^{-1}(V)$ need not imply that $f^{-1}(V)$ can be written as the union of those $U_x$ isnt it?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $x \in f^{-1} (V)$ there exists $U_x$ open such that $x\in U_x \subset f^{-1}(V)$. To show that  $\cup_{x\in f^{-1}(V)} U_x=f^{-1}(V)$ verify that each side is contained in the other. Since each $U_x$ is contained in $f^{-1}(V)$ we get LHS contained in RHS. For the other way, if $y \in f^{-1}(V)$ then $U_y$ is one of the open sets whose union is LHS, so $y \in U_y \subset LHS$.

Comment: You mention that Uy is one of the open sets.  Is it true that there is one and only one Uy that forms the member of the Union of open sets of y. Is it possible to have an open set U' containing x but not a subset of fInverse(V)?  I realize that does not invalidate the explanation of the proof as long as there is at least one which is a subset of fInverse(V), just wondering if the possibility of multiple open sets exist and if they can be not a subset of fInverse(V).

Comment: @STEMExchanger You are right. There may be lots of other open sets containing $y$ and contained in the union but we just need one such set, namely $U_y$ for the proof.

Comment: One more question on this, is it possible that For an x∈X and a neighborhood V of f(x), there is a neighborhood U of x such that V⊂f(U) and the function still continuous?

Comment: Certainly possible. For example you can have $U=X$ and $f(U)=Y$ with $f$ continuous.